# Speed - way problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Car Yellow which is of $180km/h$ and Car Purple is of $80km/h$ start going on the same way from the point A. When the more speedy car(Car Yellow) comes to point B and turn immediately(nonstop) back and come to point A, Car Purple reaches point C. What is ${AB} / {BC}$ ?

I don't understand what's wrong with me. If I say $|AB| = x $ and $|BC| = y $, and assume Car Yellow completes $2x$ way at $t$ time, at the same $t$ time I expect Car Purple should be at point C.

I find out then, $x = 90t$ and $x + y = 80t$. I don't understand.

[image]

Comment: Since you aren't interested in its value, it would be a good idea to try and eliminate $t$ from these equations. How can you do that?

Comment: @Sharkos I don't understand what I achieve by eliminating $t$s.

Answer (score 2):

$x=90t \qquad x+y=80t \to y=-10t \qquad \frac{\lvert AB \rvert}{\lvert BC \rvert}=9$

Point C is actually between A and B because Yellow is more than twice as fast as Purple, that's why $y$ is negative.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use $t = \frac{s}{v}$ where distance s and velocity v, $|AB| = x$ and $|BC| = y$.
For the yellow car it is $v_1 = 180 \frac{km}{h}$, therefore $$ t = \frac{2x}{v_1}$$ and for the purple car $v_2 = 80 \frac{km}{h}$ $$ t = \frac{x+y}{v_2}$$
Then you see how to eliminate t: $$ t = \frac{2x}{v_1} = \frac{2|AB|}{v_1}= \frac{x+y}{v_2} = \frac{|AB| + |BC|}{v_2}$$

The solution tells you that C must be between A and B.